# Add crossed diagonals

Tags: tikz-pgf

everyone, I want to draw a picture like this:
[image]
So far I got a similar one:

[image]

I want to add the crossed diagonals and numbers in the different parts separated by diagonals. Here is my code:

```
\tikzstyle{start_state} =[rectangle, draw=orange!60, fill=orange!5, very thick, minimum size=15mm]
\tikzstyle{normal_state} =[rectangle, draw=green!60, fill=green!5, very thick, minimum size=15mm]
\tikzstyle{water_state} =[rectangle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, minimum size=15mm]
\tikzstyle{terminal_state} =[rectangle, draw=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick, minimum size=15mm]

% \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{policy_arrow} = [very thick,->,>=stealth, orange]


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
%Nodes
\node[start_state] (state_1)  {\(S_1\)};
\node[normal_state] (state_2)  [right of = state_1] {\(S_2\)};
\node[normal_state] (state_3)  [right of = state_2] {\(S_3\)};
\node[normal_state] (state_4)  [below of = state_1] {\(S_4\)};
\node[water_state] (state_5)  [right of = state_4] {\(S_5\)};
\node[normal_state] (state_6)  [right of = state_5] {\(S_6\)};
\node[normal_state] (state_7)  [below of = state_4] {\(S_7\)};
\node[water_state] (state_8)  [right of = state_7] {\(S_8\)};
\node[terminal_state] (state_9)  [right of = state_8] {\(S_9\)};
%Lines
% east--west
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=2pt] state_1.east) --node[anchor = south] {-1} ([yshift=2pt] state_2.west);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=-2pt] state_2.west) --node[anchor = north] {-1} ([yshift=-2pt] state_1.east);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=2pt] state_2.east) --node[anchor = south] {-1} ([yshift=2pt] state_3.west);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=-2pt] state_3.west) --node[anchor = north] {-1} ([yshift=-2pt] state_2.east);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=2pt] state_4.east) --node[anchor = south,blue] {-3} ([yshift=2pt] state_5.west);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=-2pt] state_5.west) --node[anchor = north] {-1} ([yshift=-2pt] state_4.east);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=2pt] state_5.east) --node[anchor = south] {-1} ([yshift=2pt] state_6.west);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=-2pt] state_6.west) --node[anchor = north,blue] {-3} ([yshift=-2pt] state_5.east);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=2pt] state_7.east) --node[anchor = south,blue] {-3} ([yshift=2pt] state_8.west);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=-2pt] state_8.west) --node[anchor = north] {-1} ([yshift=-2pt] state_7.east);
\draw[arrow] (state_8)     -- node[anchor = south, red] {+5} (state_9);
% south--north
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=2pt] state_1.south) --node[anchor = west] {-1} ([xshift=2pt] state_4.north);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-2pt] state_4.north) --node[anchor = east] {-1} ([xshift=-2pt] state_1.south);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=2pt] state_2.south) --node[anchor = west,blue] {-3} ([xshift=2pt] state_5.north);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-2pt] state_5.north) --node[anchor = east] {-1} ([xshift=-2pt] state_2.south);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=2pt] state_3.south) --node[anchor = west] {-1} ([xshift=2pt] state_6.north);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-2pt] state_6.north) --node[anchor = east] {-1} ([xshift=-2pt] state_3.south);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=2pt] state_4.south) --node[anchor = west] {-1} ([xshift=2pt] state_7.north);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-2pt] state_7.north) --node[anchor = east] {-1} ([xshift=-2pt] state_4.south);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=2pt] state_5.south) --node[anchor = west,blue] {-3} ([xshift=2pt] state_8.north);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-2pt] state_8.north) --node[anchor = east,blue] {-3} ([xshift=-2pt] state_5.south);
\draw[arrow] (state_6)     -- node[anchor = west,red] {+5} (state_9);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: If one of the solutions fulfills your need, please accept it to let know everyone that your question is not pending anymore.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. My first time asks questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a starting point, you can use the following:

[image: matrix of crossed nodes with figures]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\newcommand{\cross}[5]
    {
    \def\shft{1pt}
    \draw   ([xshift=\shft,yshift=-\shft)]#1.north west) -- ([xshift=-\shft,yshift=\shft)]#1.south east)
            ([xshift=-\shft,yshift=-\shft)]#1.north east) -- ([xshift=\shft,yshift=\shft)]#1.south west);
    \def\l{6pt}
    \node [above=\l] at (#1.center) {#2}; 
    \node [right=\l] at (#1.center) {#3}; 
    \node [below=\l] at (#1.center) {#4}; 
    \node [left=\l] at (#1.center) {#5}; 
    }

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{start_state} =[rectangle, draw=orange!60, fill=orange!5, very thick, minimum size=15mm,,label={[label distance=-2mm]-45:$#1$}]
\tikzstyle{normal_state} =[rectangle, draw=green!60, fill=green!5, very thick, minimum size=15mm,label={[label distance=-2mm]-45:$#1$}]
\tikzstyle{water_state} =[rectangle, draw=blue!60, fill=blue!5, very thick, minimum size=15mm,,label={[label distance=-2mm]-45:$#1$}]
\tikzstyle{terminal_state} =[rectangle, draw=red!60, fill=red!5, very thick, minimum size=15mm,,label={[label distance=-2mm]-45:$#1$}]

% \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{policy_arrow} = [very thick,->,>=stealth, orange]


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
%Nodes
\node[start_state=S_1] (state_1)  {};
\node[normal_state=S_2,right of = state_1] (state_2) {};
\node[normal_state=S_3] (state_3)  [right of = state_2] {};
\node[normal_state=S_4] (state_4)  [below of = state_1] {};
\node[water_state=S_5] (state_5)  [right of = state_4] {};
\node[normal_state=S_6] (state_6)  [right of = state_5] {};
\node[normal_state=S_7] (state_7)  [below of = state_4] {};
\node[water_state=S_8] (state_8)  [right of = state_7] {};
\node[terminal_state=S_9] (state_9)  [right of = state_8] {};

% Crosses and figures
\cross{state_1}{6}{0}{4}{1}
\cross{state_2}{5}{}{}{2}
\cross{state_3}{}{}{4}{}
\cross{state_4}{1}{}{3}{9}

%Lines
% east--west
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=2pt] state_1.east) --node[anchor = south] {-1} ([yshift=2pt] state_2.west);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=-2pt] state_2.west) --node[anchor = north] {-1} ([yshift=-2pt] state_1.east);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=2pt] state_2.east) --node[anchor = south] {-1} ([yshift=2pt] state_3.west);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=-2pt] state_3.west) --node[anchor = north] {-1} ([yshift=-2pt] state_2.east);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=2pt] state_4.east) --node[anchor = south,blue] {-3} ([yshift=2pt] state_5.west);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=-2pt] state_5.west) --node[anchor = north] {-1} ([yshift=-2pt] state_4.east);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=2pt] state_5.east) --node[anchor = south] {-1} ([yshift=2pt] state_6.west);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=-2pt] state_6.west) --node[anchor = north,blue] {-3} ([yshift=-2pt] state_5.east);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=2pt] state_7.east) --node[anchor = south,blue] {-3} ([yshift=2pt] state_8.west);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=-2pt] state_8.west) --node[anchor = north] {-1} ([yshift=-2pt] state_7.east);
\draw[arrow] (state_8)     -- node[anchor = south, red] {+5} (state_9);
% south--north
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=2pt] state_1.south) --node[anchor = west] {-1} ([xshift=2pt] state_4.north);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-2pt] state_4.north) --node[anchor = east] {-1} ([xshift=-2pt] state_1.south);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=2pt] state_2.south) --node[anchor = west,blue] {-3} ([xshift=2pt] state_5.north);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-2pt] state_5.north) --node[anchor = east] {-1} ([xshift=-2pt] state_2.south);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=2pt] state_3.south) --node[anchor = west] {-1} ([xshift=2pt] state_6.north);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-2pt] state_6.north) --node[anchor = east] {-1} ([xshift=-2pt] state_3.south);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=2pt] state_4.south) --node[anchor = west] {-1} ([xshift=2pt] state_7.north);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-2pt] state_7.north) --node[anchor = east] {-1} ([xshift=-2pt] state_4.south);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=2pt] state_5.south) --node[anchor = west,blue] {-3} ([xshift=2pt] state_8.north);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-2pt] state_8.north) --node[anchor = east,blue] {-3} ([xshift=-2pt] state_5.south);
\draw[arrow] (state_6)     -- node[anchor = west,red] {+5} (state_9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is not optimal, since everything can be automatized by creating a newcommand but anyway. You can also add a 6th argument if you want the lines to be drawn in a different colour, for example.

Comment: This is really really amazing!!! Thank you !!!!!!!!

Comment: @Juan Castaño I really have difficulty in identifying the most beautiful output.

Comment: @Sebastiano, the output is very similar but SebGlav's solution is more customizable than mine. I posted mine only to give another way to do it.

Comment: @JuanCastaño For my humble opinion they are very nice.

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility using a `pic` that takes as arguments the name of the node (the number, to be precise), the group of numbers inside the square and the group of numbers with the arrows (both taken anticlockwise). The arrows are drawn only if their number is greater than a fixed lower bound.

I think this way is simple but it has limitations. If we want to add colors to the arrow numbers it would take a lot of parameters so I prefer all the numbers in black.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\def\lv{-10} % lower value for the numbers over the arrows
             % this number is not drawn, neither the arrow
             % bigger numbers are drawn
\tikzset
{%
  start/.style   ={draw=orange!60,fill=orange!5,very thick},
  normal/.style  ={draw=green!60, fill=green!5, very thick},
  water/.style   ={draw=blue!60,  fill=blue!5,  very thick},
  terminal/.style={draw=red!60,   fill=red!5,   very thick},
  pics/state/.style n args={3}{% name (number), inner numbers (E,N,W,S); numbers over the arrows starting here (same order)
    code={%
      \foreach\i [count=\xi] in {#3}
      {
        \ifnum\i > \lv
          \begin{scope}[rotate=90*\xi-90]
            \draw[thin,black,-stealth] (0.78,0.1) --++ (1.44,0);
            \node at (1.5,0.4) {$\i$};
        \end{scope}
       \fi
      }
      \filldraw (-0.75,-0.75) rectangle (0.75, 0.75);
      \draw     (-0.75,-0.75) --        (0.75, 0.75);
      \draw     (-0.75, 0.75) --        (0.75,-0.75);
      \node[fill,inner sep=1pt] at (0,0) {$S_{#1}$};
      \foreach\i [count=\xi] in {#2}
        \node at (90*\xi-90:0.5)  {\i};
    }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic[start]    at (0, 0) {state={1}{2,0,,}{-1,\lv,\lv,-1}};
\pic[normal]   at (3, 0) {state={2}{3,,1,1}{-1,\lv,-1,-3}};
\pic[normal]   at (6, 0) {state={3}{,,2,4}{\lv,\lv,-1,-1}};
\pic[normal]   at (0,-3) {state={4}{1,1,,1}{-3,-1,\lv,-1}};
\pic[water]    at (3,-3) {state={5}{4,2,0,2}{-1,-1,-1,-3}};
\pic[water]    at (6,-3) {state={6}{,3,1,5}{\lv,-1,-3,+5}};
\pic[normal]   at (0,-6) {state={7}{2,0,,}{-3,-1,\lv,\lv}};
\pic[water]    at (3,-6) {state={8}{5,1,1}{+5,-3,-1,\lv}};
\pic[terminal] at (6,-6) {state={9}{}{\lv,\lv,\lv,\lv}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you !!!!! Looks really great!

Answer (score 2):

Just another solution using a `path picture` to draw inner crosses and `labels` for values inside nodes. General distribution is made with a `matrix`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\tikzset
{%
  basenode/.style = {minimum size=1.5cm, very thick, draw=#1!60, fill=#1!5},    
  cross/.style 2 args ={basenode=#2, 
    label={[fill=#2!5, circle, inner sep=1pt]center:#1},
    path picture={\draw (path picture bounding box.north west) -- (path picture bounding box.south east);
      \draw (path picture bounding box.north east) -- (path picture bounding box.south west);},
    },
    labels/.style n args={4}{
        label={[anchor=west]west:#1},
        label={[anchor=north]north:#2},
        label={[anchor=east]east:#3},
        label={[anchor=south]south:#4},
    },
    arrow/.style={thick, >=stealth,->}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix(A)[column sep=2cm, row sep=2cm] {
\node[cross={$S_1$}{orange}, labels={}{}{2}{0}] (S1) {}; &
\node[cross={$S_2$}{green}, labels={1}{}{3}{1}] (S2) {}; &
\node[cross={$S_3$}{green}, labels={2}{}{}{4}] (S3) {}; \\
\node[cross={$S_4$}{orange}, labels={}{1}{1}{1}] (S4) {}; &
\node[cross={$S_5$}{green}, labels={0}{7}{4}{2}] (S5) {}; &
\node[cross={$S_6$}{green}, labels={1}{3}{}{5}] (S6) {}; \\
\node[cross={$S_7$}{orange}, labels={}{0}{2}{}] (S7) {}; &
\node[cross={$S_8$}{green}, labels={1}{1}{5}{}] (S8) {}; &
\node[basenode=red] (S9) {0}; \\
};

\foreach \i/\j/\k in {1/2/-1, 2/3/-1, 5/6/-1}
    \draw[arrow] ([yshift=2mm]S\i.east)--node[above]{\k} ([yshift=2mm]S\j.west);
\foreach \i/\j/\k in {4/5/-3, 7/8/-3}
    \draw[arrow] ([yshift=2mm]S\i.east)--node[above,blue]{\k} ([yshift=2mm]S\j.west);
\foreach \i/\j/\k in {2/1/-1, 3/2/-1,5/4/-1,8/7/-1}
    \draw[arrow] ([yshift=-2mm]S\i.west)--node[below]{\k} ([yshift=-2mm]S\j.east);
\draw[arrow] ([yshift=-2mm]S6.west)--node[below,blue]{-3} ([yshift=-2mm]S5.east);
\draw[arrow] (S8)--node[above, red]{+5}(S9);


\foreach \i/\j/\k in {1/4/-1, 3/6/-1, 4/7/-1}
    \draw[arrow] ([xshift=2mm]S\i.south)--node[right]{\k} ([xshift=2mm]S\j.north);
\foreach \i/\j/\k in {2/5/-3, 5/8/-3}
    \draw[arrow] ([xshift=2mm]S\i.south)--node[right,blue]{\k} ([xshift=2mm]S\j.north);
\foreach \i/\j/\k in {4/1/-1,5/2/-1,6/3/-1,7/4/-1}
    \draw[arrow] ([xshift=-2mm]S\i.north)--node[left]{\k} ([xshift=-2mm]S\j.south);
\draw[arrow] ([xshift=-2mm]S8.north)--node[left,blue]{-3} ([xshift=-2mm]S5.south);
\draw[arrow] (S6)--node[above, right]{+5}(S9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I not have forgotten the 2nd user that I have known in TeX.SE. Very nice also this example. +1